# Database searches in separate files

Tags: python, c#, vba

I am looking for a kind of database which can search in separate files eg. pdf, xls, doc that I get from different suppliers. My idea is something like this:
For example, I need to search for a part number and check different data about it. The file containing the part number must then be opened with the part number marked. If there are multiple hits, the database should display a list of the various files containing the searched item number. The list should act as links that open the file with the item number selected when selecting one from the list.

Does this already exist or how do I approach it?

Today, it's all assembled into a single PDF file of more than 1000 pages, and it's a time-consuming and laborious process to maintain.

I've only used vba in connection with Excel, so maybe it's too complicated for me. But is it possible for a programmer without spending 1000 hours on it?

Please help me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Either Access or Excel could do this.  I noticed the Python tag.  I'm sure Python could handle this as well, although it seems more like a database solution would be best.  It sounds like a one-to-many scenario.  See the link below for some ideas of how this technique works.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ms_access/ms_access_one_to_many_relationship.htm

Also, below is a link with a whole bunch of MS Access templates.  Take a look at that and hopefully that will give you some ideas of how to get started.

https://www.microsoftaccessexpert.com/Microsoft-Access-Templates.aspx

I agree, keeping this in a PDF with 1000 pages is NOT the way to go!!